# How to config the GEODE to use less memory

Tags: geode

We are trying to save 4.5M (150Mb) of keys and the GEODE server already eats ~3.5Gb of RAM , any idea how we can offload less recently used to the disc.

```
<region name="test">
    <region-attributes data-policy="replicate" scope="distributed-ack">
      <eviction-attributes>
        <lru-memory-size action="overflow-to-disk" maximum="100"/>
      </eviction-attributes>
    </region-attributes>
  </region>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you followed the "[Configuring Data Eviction](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/10/developing/eviction/configuring_data_eviction.html)" docs and had problems ?

Comment: looks like keys are saved in the mem with no option to config that

Comment: That's correct, keys are always in memory, unless your eviction action is "destroy".

Comment: New URL is: http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/developing/eviction/configuring_data_eviction.html